# Shift down cells on enter in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice-calc

In Libreoffice Calc, how does one shift down cells on press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and if I want to go down cells by pressing <kbd>↓</kbd>? Is there any setting that controls this?

Answer (score 2):

In OpenOffice Calc you can do this from Tools->Customize->Keyboard then choose the key "Enter", the Category "Insert" and the Function "Insert Cells Down".

I know LibraOffice has the same screen, but I'm not positive it has the same options.

Comment: Exists in LibreOffice 4.2.8.2, if you select `Return` instead of Enter.

Comment: can do both "Insert Cells Down" and "Move down" on enter key?